# Is there any benefit to using quick chat with the bots in Left 4 Dead 2?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

In Left 4 Dead 2 you can make your character speak by clicking in the thumbstick on controller, or pressing Z or X when using a keyboard.

When looking at an item the quick voice line changes from generic "look" to a more specific "ammo here", "weapons here" or similar. This can be useful on multiplayer campaigns where it can be used to communicate with other players if a microphone isn't available.

But on single player campaigns it doesn't seem to serve a purpose. Identifying an object doesn't immediately give a voice response and there isn't much else in the way of feedback.

Is there any benefit to using quick chat in single player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has no effect on their behavior, other than sometimes they respond to you with vocalizations. However, with Left 4 Bots, you can give them vocal commands.

Comment: *Let's go. Hurry. Ready.* - those are the commands that make them talk to each other. Making Cortana complain about stuff is half the fun.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that modding (Left 4 Bots mod) could allow bots to be commanded until I've read this answer.